# Is it possible to reverse a bitshift and addition

Tags: java, reverse-engineering, bit-shift

is it possible to reverse this in java?

```
byte config = (byte)((X << 6) + Y);
```

knowing that X is 0,1,2 or 3 (2 bits) and Y is between 0 and 24 (5 bits)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reverse it with :

```
X = (config >> 6) & 0b11
Y = config & 0b11111;
```

`& 0b11` and `& 0b11111` are [bitwise operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_%28computing%29). They respectively gives you the last 2 bits and the last 5 bits of the number they are apply on.

What about arbitrary lengths ?

You can reverse the combination if and only if in the result each bit comes from x or (exclusively) y. 
In conclusion : **you need to shift x at least the length of y**.

Comment: That shoud be `Y = config & 0b11111` and `X = (config >> 6) & 0b11`.

Comment: Thanks, it works. However, before I accept, can you please explain the purpose of 0b11111 and 0b11? are they identical? and does it remain the same if Y is 6 bits?

Comment: @CaptainObvious, explanations added. It remains the same if Y is 6 bits, but it does not if Y is 7 (cause of an overlap between `X << 6` and `Y`).

Comment: Ok yes i see, but still, is 0b11111 (== 0b11??) hexadecimal representation or what is it? I don't understand how you figure out you have to use this number

Comment: 0b11111 is the binary representation of 31 (00011111), 0b11 is the binary representation of 3 (00000011)

Comment: Alright, so the amount of ones is equal to the amount of bits stored per X and Y, so 2 and 5 respectively. Thanks I get it now :)